# Python + Kivy (second screen is loading blank)

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am learning kivy now... I am developing my 1st app for a friend, a very simple one. But I am facing this error:

Whenever I click "create account", the named 'Login(Screen)' loads blank. None of the widgets that I have created on my kivy file shows.

here are the codes:

==========================================================================

python file:

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager


class Gerenciador(ScreenManager):
    pass

class BoasVindas(Screen):
    pass

class Login(Screen):
    def logar(self, usuario, senha):
        print("usuario={0}, senha={1}".format(usuario, senha))

class Resultado(Screen):
    pass

class LoginApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Gerenciador()

LoginApp().run()
```

========================================================================

kivy file:

```
<Gerenciador>:
BoasVindas:
    name: 'boasvindas'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        Label:
            text:'Faça o seu Login ou crie uma nova conta'
        Button:
            text:'Login'

        Button:
            text:'Criar nova conta'
            on_release:root.current='login'


Login:
    name: 'login'
    BoxLayout:
        TextInput:
            id:usuario
            hint_text:'Usuário'
            multiline: False
        TextInput:
            id:senha
            hint_text:'Senha'  
            multiline: False
            password: True
        Button:
            id:'btn'
            text:'Ok'
            on_press: self.parent.parent.logar(usuario.text, senha.text)
            on_release:root.current='boasvindas'
```

=========================================================================

Any ideas on what I am missing? The first screen loads perfectly. If I swap the order, Login screen loads well. But the second screen is blank, no matter what content. as long as it is the second screen to load, it returns blank.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem - Second Screen Blank

There were four screens created. Two screens with children widgets and no screen names were created from the kv file. Another two screens with screen names but no children widgets were created from the Python code.

When the button, `'Criar nova conta'` was pressed to go to the screen with name, `'login'` it was using the instance that was created from the Python code which does not have any widgets in it i.e. it is blank.

## Build/Processing Sequence

In Kivy App, the order of processing is as follow. To proof this, add print() and `id()` functions into the kv file, and Python code, `__init__()` method for each screen. It will show four different screens and memory location for each screen respectively.

1. The kv file is always the first item processed.
2. The Python code is the next item to be processed.

### Snippet: Python Code - Proof Build/Processing Sequence

```
class Gerenciador(ScreenManager):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Gerenciador, self).__init__()
        print("\nGerenciador.__init__():", id(self), "\n")
        self.add_widget(Login(name='login'))
        self.add_widget(BoasVindas(name='boasvindas'))


class BoasVindas(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BoasVindas, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print("\nBoasVindas.__init__():", id(self), "\n")


class Login(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Login, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print("\nLogin.__init__():", id(self), "\n")


class TestLogin(App):

    def build(self):
        print("\nTestLogin.build():")
        return Gerenciador()
```

### Snippet: file - Proof Build/Processing Sequence

```
        Button:
            text:'Criar nova conta'
            on_release:
                print("self.parent.parent=", self.parent.parent)
                print("id(self.parent.parent)=", id(self.parent.parent))
                print("app.root.screen_names=", app.root.screen_names)
                print("app.root.screens=", app.root.screens)
                for x in app.root.screens: print("screen={0}, id(screen)={1}".format(x, id(x)))
                root.current='login'
```

## Solution

Please refer to the step-by-step solution and example for details.

### Python Code

1. Replace all constructor, `__init__()` method with `pass`

### kv file

1. Add `name` to each screen, `name: 'boasvindas'` and `name: 'login'` respectively.
2. Replace `self.parent.parent.logar(usuario.text, senha.text)` with `root.logar(usuario.text, senha.text)`

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager


class Gerenciador(ScreenManager):
    pass


class BoasVindas(Screen):
    pass


class Login(Screen):

    def logar(self, usuario, senha):
        print("usuario={0}, senha={1}".format(usuario, senha))


class Resultado(Screen):
    pass


class TesteLogin(App):

    def build(self):
       return Gerenciador()


TesteLogin().run()
```

### testelogin.kv

```
#:kivy 1.11.0

<Gerenciador>:
    BoasVindas:
        name: 'boasvindas'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation:'vertical'
            Label:
                text:'Faça o seu Login ou crie uma nova conta'  # Sign in or create a new account
            Button:
                text:'Login'

            Button:
                text:'Criar nova conta'     # Create new account
                on_release:root.current='login'

    Login:
        name: 'login'
        BoxLayout:
            TextInput:
                id:usuario
                hint_text:'Usuário'     # User
                multiline: False
            TextInput:
                id:senha
                hint_text:'Senha'   # Password
                multiline: False
                password: True
            Button:
                id:'btn'
                text:'Ok'
                on_press: self.parent.parent.logar(usuario.text, senha.text)
                on_release:root.current='boasvindas'    # Welcome
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - Second Screen]

Comment: I am ashamed to admit that my kivy file was named differently than "testelogin.kv".
Everything worked just fine after I renamed the kivy file, except for the command "on_release: root.current..." It returns me an error saying that the root has no atrribute. 

I am grateful for all the help, but why can't I find anything within the "root", I would much appreciate.
On time: when "root" is changed to "self.parent.parent..." it works flawlessly

Comment: Code updated as requested. Also, is the exact same as suggest in the comments. Any idea why root."" is not referring to proper object? thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In your `__init__()` method for `Gerenciador` you are creating the `Login` and `BoasVindas` screens, but you are also crating them in your `.kv` file. You should not do both. If you create them in the `.kv` file, here is what your code can look like:

python file:

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager


class Gerenciador(ScreenManager):
    pass

class BoasVindas(Screen):
    pass

class Login(Screen):
    pass

class Resultado(Screen):
    pass

class TesteLogin(App):

    def build(self):
       return Gerenciador()

TesteLogin().run()
```

kv file:

```
<Gerenciador>:
    BoasVindas:
        name: 'boasvindas'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation:'vertical'
            Label:
                text:'Faça o seu Login ou crie uma nova conta'
            Button:
                text:'Login'

            Button:
                text:'Criar nova conta'
                on_release:root.current='login'

    Login:
        name: 'login'
        BoxLayout:
            TextInput:
                id:usuario
                hint_text:'Usuário'
                multiline: False
            TextInput:
                id:senha
                hint_text:'Senha'
                multiline: False
                password: True
            Button:
                id:'btn'
                text:'Ok'
                #on_press:self.parent.parent.logar(usuario.text, senha.text)
                on_release:root.current='boasvindas'
```

In your `.kv` file, when a class name is surrounded by `<>`, that means that it is a template for building that class, but does not actually create the class. The classes without `<>` are created, but the ones in your `.kv` file are subordinate to the `Gerenciador` class. So, when an instance of the `Gerenciador` class is created (as in your `App.build()` method), the `Login` and `BoasVindas` screens are created as its children. Note that I added the `name` attribute to those screens in the `.kv` file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
The reason why I created the classes on the main file is that the line "name: 'login'" is not been recognized for some reason. 

when I tried to run the code you answered (with the names defined on kv file), it returns me an error " line 1065, in get_screen
     raise ScreenManagerException('No Screen with name "%s".' % name)
 kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManagerException: No Screen with name "login"."

I appreciate any further help. 

Thank you!

Comment: Just to be sure, the name of your `.kv` file is `testelogin.kv`, correct?